# How do I compare list of Rpm versions in python

Tags: python, version, rpm

I have a situation in which I have two list list1 and list2 :

list1 is prerequisites rpm for application

and list2 is the list of rpm's in the system

```
list1 = ["binutils-2.23.52.0.1-12.el7.x86_64",
        "compat-libcap1-1.10-3.el7.x86_64",
        "compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-71.el7.i686",
        "compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-71.el7.x86_64"]

list2 =['acl-2.2.51-12.el7.x86_64', 'adcli-0.8.1-3.el7.x86_64', 'audit-2.7.6-3.el7.x86_64', 'audit-libs-2.7.6-3.el7.i686',  'binutils-2.25.1-32.base.el7_4.2.x86_64','compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-72.el7.i686']
```

Created two dictionaries using regex :

```
new_dict[match.group(1)] = {"name": s, "version": match.group ( 2 ), "build": match.group ( 3 ),"os": match.group ( 4 ), "arch": match.group ( 5 )}

old_dict[match1.group ( 1 )] = {"name": i, "version": match1.group ( 2 ), "build": match1.group ( 3 ),"os": match1.group ( 4 ), "arch": match1.group ( 5 )}

t_old = old_dict['libaio']['name']
print "t_old",t_old
t_new = new_dict['libaio']['name']
print "t_new",t_new

result =rpm.compare_packages(t_new, t_old)

print result
```

The output it get :

```
t_old libaio-0.3.109-9.el7.x86_64
t_new libaio-0.3.109-13.el7.x86_64
1
t_new is newer
```

I am stuck at here for single value it works but how do I do it for all keys for old_dict ?

Comment: Why are you trying to parse it with regexes? Isn't that what `rpm.compare_packages` gives you? https://pythonhosted.org/version_utils/version_utils.rpm.html#version_utils.rpm.compare_packages implies it.

Comment: I applied regex to to get the rpm name and create a dictionary for its attributes so that using the rpm key in list 1 identify the same key in the second list and compare both names I am unable to iterate it . or if do you have other logic share it

Comment: I have not done it myself, but it looks like you can feed [rpm.package()](https://pythonhosted.org/version_utils/version_utils.rpm.html#version_utils.rpm.package) the full string and get out a class that has [everything you wanted](https://pythonhosted.org/version_utils/version_utils.common.html#version_utils.common.Package) without trying to do the regex yourself.